# Is there a relationship between viscosity and enthalpy of vaporization?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

It would be useful to be able to predict relative evaporation rates of liquids.  For small reduced temperatures the heat of vaporization is relatively constant, but it is not one of the more common properties cited for substances.

Is there any sort of functional relationship between enthalpy of vaporization and common properties like viscosity, melting point, and boiling point?

Comment: I don't believe there necessarily is one, and I considered making a plot to confirm that suspicion, but finding the data is going to be a pain since both of those properties vary with temperature. I think you would get substantially different answers with viscosity at the melting point of individual compounds vs. at a fixed temperature across all compounds. I'd be interested if someone did have the data to plot such.

Comment: @WilliamKappler: Good point.  Yes, we probably have to specify it at some standardized temperature.  Melting point is a good one.  Or perhaps the "liquid-midpoint": i.e., the temperature halfway between boiling and freezing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The phase envelope (or equilibrium curve) of most liquids have a similar shape and can be approximated, to a reasonable degree, by using the Clausius-Clapeyron equation:

$$
\Delta h_v=T(v^V-v^L)\frac{dP^s}{dT}
$$

which requires finding ${dP^s}/{dT}$ from e.g. a vapor-pressure-temperature correlation like the Antoine equation, and also a separate estimate for $\Delta v$ before $\Delta h_v$ can be obtained. This is an exact thermodynamic relationship, but is often simplified by using the ideal gas law for $v^V$ and neglecting the liquid volume $v^L$ i.e. $v^V \gg v^L$, giving

$$
\Delta h_v=\frac{RT^2}{P^s}\frac{dP^s}{dT}
$$

However, it is *very important* to note that the term $(v^V-v^L)$ becomes increasingly decisive as you go above 1 bar, where the assumption $v^V \gg v^L$ is no longer valid. In such a case, separate correlations for $v^L$ and $v^V$ are required before the correct curvature is obtained. $v^L$, for instance, can be calculated from e.g. a density correlation like the Rackett equation, and $v^v$ from an equation of state like Peng-Robinson.

Comment: Wow, so this looks like relatively cutting-edge thermodynamics: Do the Rackett and Peng-Robinson equations really date only from the 1970s?

Comment: $\Delta h_v$ is the specific enthalpy of vaporization [J/mol], $v$ the pure component molar volume for the vapor ($V$) and liquid ($L$) phases, while $P^s$ is the saturated vapor pressure ($T$ is in Kelvin).

Comment: Cutting-edge? Google the names Rudolf Clausius and Clapeyron... Not so much as cutting-edge as it is *still very relevant*. New correlations for $P^s$, $v^V$, $v^L$ or any other thermodynamic property are constantly being developed. Most of the time, however, you are only interested in answers that are sufficiently precise and that follow known trends i.e. 5 decimal place accuracy is typically not required (which is why you find many older correlations still in active use).

Comment: I'm still trying to digest this.  The differential equation form is needed to find an equilibrium, but before solving for equilibrium I like to be able to find instantaneous values.  So *given a T and P* what determines a chemical's *instantaneous* evaporation rate?  Or, put another way, holding the conditions constant and changing the chemical, what do these equations tell us?  For "everyday" *T* & *P* it looks like it reduces to saying, "Evaporation rate is proportional to saturated vapor pressure," so Clausius-Clapeyron doesn't actually relate it to other characteristics?

Comment: Thermodynamic properties are most definitely influenced by molecular characteristics, which is why different molecules have different saturated vapor pressure curves and normal boiling points (just to name a few). Therefore it is not necessarily correct to say that the Clausius-Clapeyron equation does not relate to other molecular characteristics.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to get at with this "instantaneous evaporation rate"... If you had a pot of water at $100~^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$, open to the atmosphere, then your evaporation rate should be proportional to the rate of heat that is being added. However, if you wanted to weld a lid onto the pot then things start to get *very* messy because it becomes a dynamic problem requiring additional levels of complexity involving additional heat and mass transfer equations... [Hopefully this time my latex is right ;)]

Comment: That's exactly why I'm interested in the "instantaneous" question: I'm only interested in the differences between chemicals, not in the dynamics of the phenomenon of evaporation.  By analogy: The boiling point of a chemical at standard pressure is a fundamental and universally quoted characteristic, even though in any system as soon as you start adding heat that number is going to change.  Now vapor pressure and vaporization enthalpy are, in my mind, one step removed from boiling temp., but I can't find anything that relates either to boiling point or any other "fundamental" characteristic.